# Update column issue tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

[Take a look at this](https://ibb.co/kMtSpw)

Task is to sum '***ukupna bilansna i vanbilansna aktiva***' for the same '***ID_Grupe***' after the relation between TABLE_A and TABLE_B on '***mbr***' and '***GRP_ID***' has been made.

(mbr and GRP_ID are clients id card numbers)

Afterwards, we need to update summed values in TABLE_C in the column '***IDV_REL_P_ESR_AMT***' after joining on the same '***ID_IDENTN_NUM***'.

> So you can think of ID_IDENTN_NUM,mbr and GRP_ID as same id card
>   number.

How can I do joins between three tables, along with an UPDATE and SET statements?

This is my idea:

```
UPDATE B2_INPT_CR_IP_SNPST AS c
SET IDV_REL_P_ESR_AMT = (SELECT ID_Grupe, SUM(ukupna_bilansna_i_vanbilansna_aktiva)
                         FROM rm_tb_portfolio AS a
                         INNER JOIN B2_INPT_CR_GRP_SNPST AS b ON a.mbr = b.GRP_ID
                         GROUP BY ID_Grupe)
 WHERE c.IP_IDENTN_NUM = a.mbr
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT ID_Grupe,
           sum(ukupna_bilansna_i_vanbilansna_aktiva) AS Total
    FROM rm_tb_portfolio as a
    INNER JOIN B2_INPT_CR_GRP_SNPST as b ON a.mbr = b.GRP_ID
    GROUP BY ID_Grupe
)
UPDATE c
SET c.IDV_REL_P_ESR_AMT  = c2.Total
FROM B2_INPT_CR_IP_SNPST as c1
INNER JOIN CTE AS c2 ON c1.ID_Grupe = c2.ID_Grupe;
```

If you want to do insert, you can do it in the same way:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    ....
)
INSERT INTO B2_INPT_CR_IP_SNPST(...)
SELECT ... FROM CTE;
```

But, you cannot use both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in the same sql statement. However, you can use [**`MERGE`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) in this case, to update existing rows or insert new values.

Comment: I will give it a try, another issue I have is that 'mbr' is varchar and GRP_ID is bigint, how can I cast it while joining.

Comment: @T_Dejan try `CAST(mbr AS BIGINT) = GRP_ID` assuming that it contains valid integer values.

Comment: Query executes for 1min and the says 0 rows affected.

Comment: @T_Dejan Please edit your question and add some sample data from both the two tables.

Comment: You can look at my edit and look at the hyperlink as well.